# Getting product and quotient of 2 numbers using recursion without using the * and / operators

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to learn programming and I am on the phase of learning recursion. Before this, I have successfully solve the problem but using loops. Right now, since recursion is quite interesting to me, I was wondering if I could convert the loop into a recursive method. I have done my attempts but I've been getting a sort of infinite computation whatsoever.

Can somebody give me a hand with this? Thanks.

This is my code.

```
public class RecursiveProduct {


public static void main (String[] args) {

    Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter num1: ");
    int num1 = myInput.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter num2: ");
    int num2 = myInput.nextInt();

    int product = recursiveProduct(num1, num2);

    System.out.print(num1 +" * " +num2 +" = " +product);


}

public static int recursiveProduct(int a, int b)
{
    int result = 0;

    if(b == 0)
        return result;
    else
    {
        result += a;
        return result += recursiveProduct(a, b--);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: We can't help if you don't show us your code.

Comment: Please can you show your attempts so that we can give further hints on them. There will be no use if we solve the problem for you, better you reach the solution by yourself with few hints.

Comment: hello, I have edited my post. please see my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static int recursiveProduct(int a, int b) {
  if (b == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return a + recursiveProduct(a,--b);
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to give too much for a `[homework]` question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, this is C++ code, but I will explain Java code later:

```
int function(int a, int b, int &counter,int &result){
    if(b==0 || a==0)
        return 0;
    if(counter==b)
        return 1;
    else{
        result+=a;
        counter++;
        function(a,b,counter,result);
    }
}
```

Function takes two references `int &counter` and `int result`. Unfortunately, you can't pass primitive types by reference in Java, so you should declare Wrapper class, and then call your method, something like this:

```
class MyInt{
   public int value=0;

}
```

Here you will bi 100% sure that object of `MyInt` will be passed by value, but itself is reference so you get what you want. Reimplement our function:

```
 void function(int a, int b, MyInt counter,MyInt result){
        if(b==0 || a==0)
            return 0;
        if(counter==b)
            return 1;
        else{
            result.value+=a;
            counter.value++;
            function(a,b,counter,result);
        }
    }
```

Call your method like this bellow, and everything should work:

```
int a=2,b=5;
MyInt counter=new MyInt();
MyInt result=new MyInt();
function(a,b,counter,result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there: just add `result += recursiveProduct(a, b--);` instead of just calling the function.

EDIT: call it with b- 1 not with b--

Comment: i have tried it and did the edits shown above but still not working.

Comment: I have found the reason for that ... you should call the function with b-1 instead of b--.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you simplify your code.

Something like

```
return b == 0 ? 0 : a + fn(a, b-1);
```

Comment: Nice one, but should be `--b`, otherwise you'll get StackOverflowError.